# Queries on a graph

Tags: c++, optimization, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

I need help with this problem:

There are **n** states in a country.  The states are connected to each other by undirected borders and there are total **n-1** boarders between different pairs of states. These borders form a tree. The strength of a border **i** is **str[i]**.

Each state grows some fruits. Initially, there are no fruits in any states. The rate at which a fruit is grown in city **i** is **R[i]** per unit time. A country that is defined as a tree of connected cities is considered rich at an instant if all the states contain at least **X** fruits.

A company wants to buy these fruits. It buys fruits from the state that contains the lowest production rate in the country and it visits a country only if it is rich. If there are multiple such countries, the company randomly chooses one country and buys from it.

You are required to answer **q** queries that are represented as follows:

The **i-th** query consists of three space-separated integers **a_i, b_i, c_i**. They allow you to generate  as **D_i, T_i and X_i** as **`D_i=a_i XOR ans_{i-1}, T_i=b_i XOR ans_{i-1}`** and **`X_i=c_i XOR ans_{i-1}`** where **ans_i** is the answer to **i-th** query and **ans_0=0**

At **t=0** borders whose strength value is greater than **D_i** splits apart and the remaining connected states form separate countries. Your task is to determine the total number of fruits that the company can collect at time **T_i**.

Each query is independent in nature.

You are required to answer these queries online because the input of the next query depends on the answer of the previous query.

**Input format**
First line: **n** and **q**
**n-1** lines:  Three space-separated integers **u, v, w** that represent that state **u** and state **v** share border whose strength value is **w**
Next line: **n** space-separated integers where the **i** integer is **R[i]**
**q** lines: Three space-separated integers that are defined in the question

**Output format**
For each query, print the answer in a new line.

**Constraints**
**`1<=n,q<=200000`**
**`0<=str[i],X[i],T[i],D[i]<=100000000`**
**`0<=R[i]<=100000`**
**`0<=a_i,b_i,c_i<2^62`**

**Input**

```
5 3  
1 2 1  
2 3 2  
3 4 3  
4 5 4  
1 2 3 4 5  
0 2 7  
16 17 26  
27 19 18
```

**Output**

```
18
27
112
```

**Explanation**
first query, since d=0, all cities form individual countries. So min. rate is the same as the max rate for each country since it contains a single city. Cities that can produce at least 7 unit of fruits in 2-time units are city 4 and 5. Answer is (4+5)*2 = 18

second query, d=2, t=3, x=8. d=2 makes 3 countries - first formed by 1--2--3, second consisting of only 4 and third of only 5. Again only 4 and 5 passes the criteria, and the answer is (4+5)*3 = 27

third query, d=0, t=8, x=9. All cities are a separate country. Eligible cities to buy fruit are 2,3,4 and 5. Answer is (2+3+4+5)*8 = 112

**I tried to do DFS for every query and block the edges that we can't use in that query, but that solution was to slow as it had O(q*n) time complexity. Can someone please give me some hint on what should I do to solve this problem more efficiently?

Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Welcome to tack Overflow. Why are you using DFS? What data structure(s) are you using?

Comment: @Beta Well, I used DFS for each query to get lowest production rate for every rich country, so that I could calculate the answer as (sum of lowest production rates from rich countries * T_i)

Comment: And why are you doing it for *every query?*

Comment: @Beta Well queries are independent, so for each query we will have different D_i, that means that for each query we will have different looking countries so I needed to recalculate everything. I don't know how to precompute all that I need and than answer queries efficiently. Do you have idea how to do that?

Comment: Unless you can provide a C++ code for this problem, I believe this question belongs to [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).